# Use of undeclared type 'valueMirror' when using Mirror

Tags: swift

I am trying to map a struct to other class that have same properties. but it keep showing this error

> Use of undeclared type 'valueMirror'

My code

```
extension Mapper {
    func map<T:Object>(to type: T.Type){
        let object = T()
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for property in m.children {
            guard let key = property.label else { continue }
            let value = property.value
            let valueMirror = Mirror(reflecting: value)

            if valueMirror.displayStyle == .collection {
                let array = value as! valueMirror.subjectType // <-- error
                object.setValue(array.asRealMList, forKey: key)
            } else {
                object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which type is `asRealMList` declared? You should cast `value` to that type instead of `valueMirror.subjectType`, because `valueMirror.subjectType` is not a type as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @Sweeper I want to map arrays to to realm list, so source object have Array<something> and the destination has List<Array> so I am using array extension to map arrays to realm lists.

Comment: Then try `as! [Any]` instead.

Comment: You are right, please write your comment as answer to select it as the correct answer for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueMirror.subjectType` is not a type as far as the compiler is concerned. There must be a compile time type after `as!`.

Since the only place you are using `array` is in `array.asRealMList`, you probably just need to cast `value` to a type that has the property `asRealMList`. As you said in the comments, this is an extension on `Array`.

Luckily `Array` is covariant, so even without knowing which type of array it is, you'll be able to cast any array to `[Any]`:

```
let array = value as! [Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

`valueMirror.subjectType` is of type `Any.Type`.
You probably want to cast `value` to `Any`.